# How to compare two tables access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with same no.of columns and same column names , datatype of columns are same as each other but one of the table will have some extra records. How do i find those.

Table 1

```
        Name     Description       EID  

       name1      ssdad          1001
       name2      gfd            1002
       name3      gfdsffsdf      1003
```

Table 2

```
        Name     Description       EID  

       name1      ssdad          1001
       name2      gfd            1002
       name3      gfdsffsdf      1003
       name2      gfd12344       1002
       name3      gfdsffsdf      1003
       name5      gfd            1002
       name6      gfdsffsdf      1003
```

How do i specify that in query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solving Query Requirements Through the Access Query Wizard

`SQL` is the best route in this situation.  I tried looking at built-in `ACCESS` db functionality because it is likely that most people who find this solution *think* in the style of the Access Database ecosystem.  Anyways, it might be nice to show an Access UI-friendly design approach...

These are my two tables and their sample data:

**Table 1: (Has more records)**

[image: Find Unmatched Data Query in Access: Sample Table 1]

**Table 2:**

[image: Find Unmatched Data Query in Access: Sample Table 2]

There is a wizard which designs a query object which resembles the OP's request:

[image: Access: Find Unmatched Query Wizard Option]

Opting to further modify the design however, reveals a limitation:  A given table relationship cannot define more than **TWO JOINS MAXIMUM**.  The three column example of the OP would not be satisfied with additional work.

[image: Find Unmactched Query Joins]

### Alternate Approach Through Subqueries

An alternate translation of a three-column equi-join is a concatenated string representing all three column values inside of a single column.  This would get over the join limitation.  I created `Query1` and `Query2` which selected all columns from `Table1` and `Table2` (respectively), with a third column defined by the following Access DB expression builder:

```
 -- For Query1:
 [Table 1]![Name_Col] + [Table 1]![Description_Col] + Str( [Table 1]![EID] )     


 -- For Query2:
 [Table 2]![Name_Col] + [Table 2]![Description_Col] + Str( [Table 2]![EID] )
```

Applying the same wizard, except for joining `Query1` and `Query2` on the new `COMPOSITE KEY` value derived from the three original data columns.

[image: Joining Sub Query Results on Composite Join Key Value]

**The Final Results:**

[image: Find Unmatched Results Between Tables]

So Access DB users have their own native approaches to set operations and data manipulation.  Now that there is both a `SQL` and an `ACCESS` db approach posted in response, there can be some comparison analysis of how each approach decomposes the problem at hand.  Enjoy!

Comment: The wizards are a real big advantage of MS Access.

Comment: Hell of an answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

To find those extra in table2:

```
select 
   *
from
  table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name 
                     and t1.description = t2.description 
                     and t1.eid = t2.eid
where
  t1.name is null
```

Comment: The convention is to use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @Remou, thats what I had, but I doubted myself.